# build root for blackfin processor

Tags: build, root, building

i am trying to build a buildroot2011.08 for blackfin processor. i am facing following error in defconfig .

cp /home/santhosh/Desktop/santhosh/buildroot2011.08_bfin/buildroot-2011.08/output/build/linux-2.6.39.4/arch/blackfin/configs/myboard_defconfig /home/santhosh/Desktop/santhosh/buildroot2011.08_bfin/buildroot-2011.08/output/build/linux-2.6.39.4/arch/blackfin/configs/buildroot_defconfig
cp: cannot stat `/home/santhosh/Desktop/santhosh/buildroot2011.08_bfin/buildroot-2011.08/output/build/linux-2.6.39.4/arch/blackfin/configs/myboard_defconfig': No such file or directory
make: *** [/home/santhosh/Desktop/santhosh/buildroot2011.08_bfin/buildroot-2011.08/output/build/linux-2.6.39.4/.stamp_configured] Error 1

can anybody come across these error please let me know.

regards
santhosh babu